# Date parsing is updating the month

Tags: parsing, date, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code i am using to parse a date in the expected format of "DD/MM"/YYY" for Intake_date which is "2015-04-20"

```
String INTAKE_DATE = rs.getString("INTAKE_DATE"); //"2015-04-20"
System.out.println(INTAKE_DATE);
java.text.DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
Date date1 = (Date)formatter1.parse(INTAKE_DATE);
System.out.println(date1);
SimpleDateFormat newFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy");
INTAKE_DATE = newFormat1.format(date1);
System.out.println(INTAKE_DATE);
```

Below is what the system prints, and changes the month from "04" to "01"

2015-04-20

Tue Jan 20 00:00:00 CST 2015

20/01/2015

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

After trying few different things this is the work around that i found, but that still doesn't explain the previous code where month is randomly changing the month to Jan(01).

```
String intake1 =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(INTAKE_DATE))).toString();
```